# Retrieving data based on the ID java

Tags: java

i wanted to retrieve the data from the database with ID.. So, i wanted to do like this: i have number on my combobox 1 to 4. Whenever i select 1 in combobox, the textbox firstname and lastname text will be change based on the selected id. How do i do that?

I already tried like this, but it won't work:

```
private void Edit(Connection conn, Statement state, ResultSet result)
    {
        try
        {
            String driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
            Class.forName(driver);

            String url = "jdbc:odbc:Database";

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

            String query = "select FirstName, LastName, Status, JoinedDate from Customer where ID = ?";

            PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(query);

            statement.setInt(1, jComboBox1.getSelectedIndex());

            result = statement.executeQuery();

            while(result.next())
            {
                jTextField3.setText("FirstName");
                jTextField2.setText("LastName");
                jTextField3.setText("Status");
                JoinedDateLabel.setText("JoinedDate");
            }
        } 

        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());

            _sound.PlaySound(2);

            _infoBox.ShowMessageBox(e.getMessage(), "Error", 2);

            _reminder = new Reminder(1);

            JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Program will be closed due to error!", "Error", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, new Object[]{}, null);

            System.exit(0);
        }
```

Thank you

Comment: *but it won't work:* means what?your question is not clear.You have just posted the code but didnt mention about whether you get any error or output is not as per your requiremnt.merely posting code with out proper description attracts downvotes not answer

Comment: whenever i run the program, the jComboBox shows the text "Item1, item2, item3 and item4 by default" <-- i didn't change anything, i just put the comboBox to the design and put some code to retrieve the data. But the textboxes didn't change based on the selected comboBox

Comment: one question sir, how do i retrieve the number in the combobox to be based on the database? so, if in the database got 5 id's, then in the combobox also got 5 id's, if got 6 id's, then in the combobox also got 6 id's

Comment: I dont know much in swing/awt but I can help you in JDBC.I think that jComboBox1.getSelectedIndex() doesnt change when you click the combobox so the text boxes are not changed and for this only i said to give some number

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
while(result.next())
{
    jTextField1.setText(result.getString("FirstName"));
    jTextField2.setText(result.getString("LastName"));
    jTextField3.setText(result.getString("Status"));
    JoinedDateLabel.setText(result.getString("JoinedDate"));
}
```

All you're doing with your current code is setting the text to the strng literal "FirstName". You need to actually retrieve the data from the `ResultSet` and set the text as that data.

Also, note JComboBox indices are 0 based. So if you are selecting the first index, it would return 0. You should make sure (in your case) that the db has Id's of 0,1,2,3